# Deselected node keeps being selected

Tags: c#, treeview

I have created a custom handler for my TreeView control:

```
public class TreeViewOnlyLeavesSelectable : TreeView
{
    protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            this.SelectedNode = null;
            this.Refresh();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it still selects non-leaf nodes. I have debugged it, it executes if statement correctly, but in the application the node is still selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code (`e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0`) you only want NON-leaf nodes to be selectable.

According to your description ("it still selects non-leaf nodes") you only want leaf-nodes to be selectable.

Other than that, consider overriding `OnAfterSelect` instead. That also works when the keyboard is used instead of the mouse.

The following code only allows leaf-nodes to be selectable.

```
protected override void OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnAfterSelect(e);
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count != 0)
    {
        this.SelectedNode = null;
    }
}
```